# Using ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder to iterate through folders and create mosaic

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, mosaic, iterator

I am trying to create one mosaic from every month of the year. I have 3 folders with raster files for each month. So I have been trying to create 12 different mosaics from these files without success. I have tried to use almost every single iteration in the ModelBuilder. I am able to do it manually by choosing the 3 different rasters and using the "Mosaic to new raster" tool.

Example of files:

```
folder 1 
    rasterfilename_1
    rasterfilename_2
    rasterfilename_3...
folder 2 
    rasterfilename_1
    rasterfilename_2
    rasterfilename_3...
folder 3 
    rasterfilename_1
    rasterfilename_2
    rasterfilename_3...
```

What I want:

```
mosaicRaster1 = 
    folder 1\rasterfilename_1 + 
    folder 2\rasterfilename_1 + 
    folder 3\rasterfilename_1 + ...
mosaicRaster2 = 
    folder 1\rasterfilename_2 + 
    folder 2\rasterfilename_2 + 
    folder 3\rasterfilename_2 + ...
```

...

Comment: Can you include a screen shot of raster folders?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. But as a close example:

Folder 1:

rasterfilename_1
rasterfilename_2
...
rasterfilename_12
,
Folder 2:

rasterfilename_1
rasterfilename_2
...
rasterfilename_12
,
Folder 3:

rasterfilename_1
rasterfilename_2
...
rasterfilename_12